# Node.JS socket io connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How can I put the server IP address when I connect to the server in the frontend?

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/panel');
```

So instead localhost put the correspondent server IP address for the production environment.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes that's all. Or you put the hostname instead of the IP.

Comment: So, it is not possible to detect automatically the IP or the hostname?

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thanks...it was easy yes but sometimes you do not see the solution :(

Comment: In a production environment, you would typically refer to a DNS  hostname such as `http://www.google.com` though you would of course use your own registered DNS name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this Javascript is executing in the client, you can just do the following:

`document.location.hostname` contains the hostname, and `document.location.port` the port. It's as easy as that.